# Keras ImageDataGenerator.flow filenames

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, generator, saving-data

I have a folder full of 2500 numbered images and a `labels.txt` file with comma separated labels in the order of the image filename numbers.

I'd like to generate random rotations (10x the number of original training samples, 25000 total), save the new images with numbered names from 1 to 25000, then create a new `labels.txt` file with comma separated label values in the order of the numbered images.

The main problem I am having with this approach is that I can't seem to either set `batch_size` to be larger than the total number of images (ideally), or set `save_prefix` to an iterator that counts images disregarding batch number (since if I do 10 batches of 2500 I think the names will get messed up). Is there any way to do this? Here's my code so far:

```
n_images = 2500    

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=180)

# fit parameters from data
datagen.fit(X_train)

# configure batch size and retrieve one batch of images
for X_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(X_train, y_train,
                                     seed=42,
                                     batch_size=10*n_images, 
                                     save_to_dir=augment_path, 
                                     save_prefix='aug', 
                                     save_format='png', 
                                     shuffle=False):

    # convert labels back and write to file
    nums = y_batch.argmax(axis=1)+1
    write_labels = ','.join([str(i) for i in nums.tolist()])+','
    f = open(augment_path+"/labels.txt", "a+")
    f.write(write_labels)
    f.close()

    break
```

Also, what does the last number added to the saved images indicate? For example, `aug_0_1685.png`.